# Single Sign-On for Azure Virual Desktop

Tags: azure, vdi, openid

I have the following scenario:
A web applications has OIDC authentication/authorization. Using a token from an authenticated user of this application I want to start a RDP session on an Azure Virtual Desktop.

On the Azure desktop I do not want to present an additional credentials prompt but just use the identity of the web user.

Is there any solution that can provide this (Okta, PingIdentity, ...)? Azure Desktop does not support external identities, this is why I am looking for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

No, Azure virtual desktop only supports login with Azure AD Credentials.